# Skip first post on Category Archive

Tags: pagination, archives, pre-get-posts

I have created a filter to skip first post of the archive on "podcast" category.
Below is the code.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'amd_limit_posts');
function amd_limit_posts($query){
    if (is_category('podcast')){
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 4);
        $query->set('offset', 1);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

It is working but on other pages of pagination, it shows same records as on first record. So pagination links (next/prev) are working fine. But the records it is showing are the same as on first page.

How do I fix this?

Comment: 'offset' does not work with pagination - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Wordpress Documentation available here, you'll be able to do what you want to do by using two hooks:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

> Unfortunately, many developers find out that hard way that setting an offset value in their custom WordPress queries has the nasty and potentially serious side-effect of breaking pagination.
>
> There is a very good reason for this however... the offset argument is actually the value WordPress uses to handle pagination itself. If a developer sets a manual offset value, pagination will not function because that value will override WordPress's automatic adjustment of the offset for a given page.
>
> In order to use an offset in WordPress queries without losing WordPress's pagination features, you will need to manually handle some basic pagination calculations. This can accomplished with the following two hooks
>
> `pre_get_posts - This hook allows tweaking of queries before they are run. Here we need to ensure that our offset is applied only to the first page.`
>
> `found_posts - Allows correction of WordPress's query result count. This allows us to ensure WordPress takes our offset into account for pages other than the first page.`